# parameters & scope in functions

Tags: php, scope

i have a question in PHP related to the parameters of a function and their scope.

I am building an own little template system and currently i keep using:

```
try {
    $ret = include("file.php");
    if(!$ret) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    // Go on here...
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    // error handling
}
```

about 3-4 times in the mainfile `index.php`. This code first includes the needed file (set by GET parameters in the URL), trys to include it and if it fails it handles all errors. Since this is used 3-4 times in index.php i want to make a function out of it so i can easily call `$Template->LoadFile("filename.php");` and this function handles everything for me: Including, Executing the code and error handling.

Not that hard i thought, but when doing so i get a lot of error messages because the variables needed by the included file for its execution are only avaiable in the scope of `index.php` (where the code was executed before) and not in the scope of the `LoadFile()` function. What can i do now?

- Revert everything back and again use this above code 3-4 times stupidly?
- Add all needed variables in `LoadFile()` as parameters so by using `$Template->LoadFile($file,$vars);` `$vars` would be available for use in `LoadFile()` for the included File? By doing so the given parameters would be huge in some cases. For example if i add an own board, the $vars would contain every board data and thats quite much. Wouldn't that make the template system really slow?
- Add the needed variables via parameters as reference? (same as my 2nd suggest, but with less engine slowdown).
- use globals? NO!

What options are there else? Thank's a lot :)

Comment: I know some people advise against doing so, but I'd use global within the function.

Comment: I thought `include` was just a language construct - not a function in itself?  Can you use it like that and have it return something?!

Comment: Yes you can use include like that. PHP 5+. "include returns false on failure". And if the included file has return $Data, then $Data will be returned to $Var, when $Var = include($File);

Comment: Ye, just tested it - thx, not sure I like that behaviour though :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use option2 but in variety of other ways, have a look at how codeigniter and kohana render their views.

you can do something like

`$Template->LoadFile($file, $vars)`
where $vars is an `array` like `array('thisIsVariableName' => 'thisIsVariableValue')`

or

```
$Template->file($file)
->vars('thisIsVariableName', thisIsVariableValue)
->multi_var(array('thisIsVariableName2' => 'thisIsVariableValue2'))
->render();
```

In case of the template size, then you can always split a template into subtemplates.